# How can I make it so that the output to my payloadfactory has opening and closing xml tags instead of just one self contained <tag />?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am building an xml payload out of a JSON payload but whenever I have missing fields from the JSON which are optional for my endpoint instead of producing

```
<ActionItem></ActionItem>
```

the payload factory will produce

```
<ActionItem/>
```

which is semantically identical. However I need the tags to open and close as my endpoint has errors with self closing tags so how can I modify this in order to do that?

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
      <soap:Body>
        <hom:ActionItem$1</hom:ActionItem>
      </soap:Body>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$.ActionItem"/>
    <args>
</payloadFactory>
```

I attempted to simply do the following but integration studio won't save the file without first removing all of the "</ arg>" tags.

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
      <soap:Body>
        <hom:ActionItem$1</hom:ActionItem>
      </soap:Body>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$.ActionItem"></arg>
    <args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible unless you write a custom message formatter. WSO2 uses STAX parser to build the XML which will always do this conversion. The only workaround is to add a space as a value. This will only work if your endpoint trims the value before using it.

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
      <soap:Body>
        <hom:ActionItem> $1</hom:ActionItem>
      </soap:Body>
    </format>
    <args>
      <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$.ActionItem"/>
    <args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Also, a class mediator may also work, but you will have to investigate and see.